# On the complex series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am studying the complex series $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{n}$$ when $|z| = 1$ and $z \ne 1$.

I wrote down from class that in this case the series converges by Dirichlet's test. But I don't see why there exists an $M \in R$ s.t. $\Bigg| \sum_{n = 1}^{N} z^n \Bigg|   \le M$ for every positive integer $N$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, $\vert\sum_1^N z^n\vert=\vert\frac{z-z^{N+1}}{1-z}\vert\le\frac{2}{\vert 1-z \vert}$ by the triangle inequality and $\vert z\vert=1$. For $z\neq1$, this is finite, and Dirichlet's test applies.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer, I have a follow up question: what if we had $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-z)^n}{n}$ ? how would I show the existence of $M$ for this series?

Comment: If the first series you were summing was $f(z)$, then this new one is just $f(-z)$, so all convergence properties just carry over (though obviously for this new series, it's not convergent at $z=-1$, rather than at $z=1$).

Comment: Why do the convergence properties carry over? sorry I am a bit doubtful with complex series since I have only recently been introduced.

Comment: If we call $f(z)=\sum_n \frac{z^n}{n}$ and $g(z)=\sum_n \frac{(-z)^n}{n}$, then the series for $g(z)$ is the same as the series for $f(-z)$, and so will be just as convergent (or not) as that series.

Answer (score 1):

On the unit circle let $z=e^{2 \pi i t}$. Then, w.l.o.g
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^Ne^{2\pi i n t}\right|=\left|\frac{e^{2\pi i t}-e^{2\pi i (N+1)t}}{1-e^{2\pi i t}}\right|\leq\frac{2}{|1-e^{2\pi i t}|}
$$
for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Which then shows that the criteria is met $\forall z \neq 1$ in this circle.